# Flask App loses connection to MySQL database after about a day

Tags: mysql, flask, pymysql, mysql-connect

I'm using python flask as a backend, running it as a  service in the GCP instance. It is working correctly once started the service. But after a day when I try to make an API call it  losses its connection with MySQL and shows the following

> error mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013:

I tried using pymysql and mysql.connector but facing the same error. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That 2013 is a line number or an error code?

Comment: It's error code, showing when I try to make any api calls next day

Comment: then you can search for "mysql 2013 error code"